# Ejb injection into Servlet with @Inject does not work

Tags: servlets, ejb, cdi, inject

I'm trying to inject EJB into servlet, but I see one problem.
I have stateless bean:

```
@Stateless
public class ServiceBean implements ServiceBeanLocal{...}
```

and servlet in another module of EAR project:

```
@WebServlet("test")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject
    ServiceBeanLocal serviceBean;
    //... doGet(), doPost()...
}
```

Both slsb and the servlet are managed by the container, so injection with CDI @Inject annotation should work without problem, but when the `doGet()` method is called, the `serviceBean` is null.
When I change @Inject to old @EJB, everything work and slsb is injected. I can't find information why, the @Inject does not work in servlets. Is it connected with the CDI specification or maybe with Wildfly/Weld?

Comment: Do you have a beans.xml?

Comment: Yes I have beans.xml with bean-discovery-mode="all". Generally wildfly does not show any errors during startup with missing dependencies, so it is weird.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong based on the information provided.  Does the version of your application server support CDI?

Comment: Try annotating your servlet class with @ManagedBean. I recently had to do this to get any injections working.

Comment: Yes, it is latest wildfly and I use @Inject a lot, but in EJB module and there is no problem with that. The problem is only with Injection EJB into servlet. Thanks peez80 I will try that out

Comment: I have this problem too, I tried `@ManagedBean` , now the servlet works but `@inject` does not. My runtime target is weblogic12c.